# How to set up (calculate) divisions in dask dataframe?

Tags: python, dask

When loading data from parquet or csv files, having the NONE divisions.
DASK docs have no information about how to set and calculate this....

How to set up and calculate right the divisions of DASK dataframe?

Comment: Have you read this [doc](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-design.html)?

Comment: Yes i read. In this doc showing how to set_index with precalculated divisions, But at what rule i need calculate divisions?

Answer (score 1):

If you read from parquet you can use `infer_divisions=True` as in this example

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_parquet("file.parq", infer_divisions=True)
```

In case you need you can directly set an index while reading

```py
df = dd.read_parquet("file.parq", index="my_col",
                     infer_divisions=True)
```

Comment: 'df = dd.read_parquet("file.parq", index="my_col", infer_divisions=True)' This works only if the index of the underlying dataset is sorted across the individual parquet files. And what solution if index is not sorted?

Comment: No, its correct. But DASK engine can not infer_divisions with unsorted index. May be another decision?

Comment: But, in dd.read_parquet("file.parq", infer_divisions=True) index need to be specified.

Comment: You can use without specify the index. In that case it's going to set a divisions over your index 0,..,n

Comment: No its doesn't, with both pyarrow and fastparquet.

Comment: ValueError: Unable to infer divisions for because no index column was discovered

Comment: Do you mind to share a sample of your df? Or create a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1):

OK, i do:

```
divisions =[part_n for part_n in range(f.npartitions)]
f = f.set_index(f.index, divisions=divisions).persist()
```

Then i do:

```
f.groupby('userId').first().compute()
```

But last operation is dramatically slow!